# change text when slider moves

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
 $(function() {
    $( ".sli3" ).slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 50,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( ".sli3_f" ).text($(this).val(  ui.value+"%" ));
        }
    });
    $( ".sli3_f" ).text($(this).val($( ".sli3" ).slider( "value" )+"%" ));
});


 <div class="sli3"><span class="sli3_f"></span></div>
```

I am trying to change text when the slider moves
nothing happens on the browser.
Any thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that the $this.val() is necessary

```
 $(function() {
    $( ".sli3" ).slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 50,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( ".sli3_f" ).text(ui.value+"%");
        }
    });
    $( ".sli3_f" ).text($( ".sli3" ).slider( "value" )+"%");
});


 <div class="sli3"><span class="sli3_f"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of mistakes.  First, you don't want to use `$(this).val(...)`.  This is just setting the value of `$(this)`, which is not what you want to do in this case.  You just want to retrieve the value, which is provided by `ui.value` when you are in the slider object's methods.  Outside of the slider's methods, you just want `$(".sli3").slider("value")`:

```
$(function() {
    $(".sli3").slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 50,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $(".sli3_f").text(ui.value + "%");
        }
    });

    $(".sli3_f").text($(".sli3").slider("value") + "%");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XjD4K/